# Proper way to communication between android app with php

Tags: android

iam making a location based app in android in which iam communicating with a server and giving some data to server now in android ican communicate with a php using DefaultHttpClient ,HttpPost/HttpGet and Http Response class  in this simple way ican take and give data to web server and another way is to make a  Rest webservice my question is which is the preferable way to communicate.

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` is not preferable and was replaced by `AndroidHttpClient` in API level 8.

Comment: but here the main problem is that either i can communicate with this simple way or i through a rest web service?

Comment: You just send URL formatted in some special way and receive responses from PHP engine.

Comment: so i dont need to implement Rest webservice

Comment: it depends on data you want to send/receive

Comment: i also need to maintain the session that webserver remember the user how is it possible and kindly please tell me for which kind of data both are suitable?

Comment: You can go with Rest webservices. In php you can use slim php for rest